# flatMap an (optional) Nested Array within a Struct is deprecated. CompactMap doesn't return desired result. (same as flatMap)

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, higher-order-functions

I have this as a struct and the populated values would be an array of array

My Goal is just to determine if the hrInt Array of Array is actually empty /  populated or Partially populated

How can I simplify this using flatMap or compactMap?

This works,
`print(intervalsWodArray.flatMap({$0.hrInt}).flatMap{$0}.flatMap{$0}.isEmpty)`
but upon compiling, Xcode is complaining about it being deprecated *('flatMap' is deprecated: Please use compactMap(_:) for the case where closure returns an optional value)* and asking me to use compactMap which does not return the desired result when the nested array is actually empty(eg: [[],[],[]])

Don't want to be doing this -

```
for i in 0..< intervalsWodArray.count { 
  if let hrInt = intervalsWodArray[i].hrInt { 
    for x in hrInt { 
      print("\(x) \(x.isEmpty)") 
    }
  }
}
```

which results in

```
[1,1] false
[] true
[] true
```

This is the playground sample example:

```
struct intervalsData : Codable {
  var intervals : [[Double]]
  var hrInt: [[Double]]?
}

var aaa = [intervalsData]()
var bbb = [intervalsData]()
var ccc = [intervalsData]()

aaa.append(intervalsData(intervals: [[0,0],[10,10]],hrInt: [[],[],[]]))
bbb.append(intervalsData(intervals: [[0,0],[10,10]],hrInt: [[1,1],[],[]]))
ccc.append(intervalsData(intervals: [[0,0],[10,10]],hrInt: [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]))
                        
print(aaa)
print(bbb)
print(ccc)

// using flatmap returns the desired output
let xxx = aaa.flatMap{$0.hrInt}.flatMap{$0}.flatMap{$0}
let yyy = bbb.flatMap{$0.hrInt}.flatMap{$0}.flatMap{$0}
let zzz = ccc.flatMap{$0.hrInt}.flatMap{$0}.flatMap{$0}

print("---Flatmap returns the Desired Output but is deprecated")
print(xxx, xxx.isEmpty)
print(yyy, yyy.isEmpty)
print(zzz, zzz.isEmpty)

// using compactMap **Does Not** returns the desired output
let a = aaa.compactMap{$0.hrInt}.compactMap{$0}.compactMap{$0}
let b = bbb.compactMap{$0.hrInt}.compactMap{$0}.compactMap{$0}
let c = ccc.compactMap{$0.hrInt}.compactMap{$0}.compactMap{$0}

print("---comactMap returns a different output then flatmap which is not desired")
print(a, a.isEmpty)
print(b, b.isEmpty)
print(c, c.isEmpty)
```

Output

```
[__lldb_expr_1254.intervalsData(intervals: [[0.0, 0.0], [10.0, 10.0]], hrInt: Optional([[], [], []]))]
[__lldb_expr_1254.intervalsData(intervals: [[0.0, 0.0], [10.0, 10.0]], hrInt: Optional([[1.0, 1.0], [], []]))]
[__lldb_expr_1254.intervalsData(intervals: [[0.0, 0.0], [10.0, 10.0]], hrInt: Optional([[1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 2.0], [3.0, 3.0]]))]
---Flatmap returns the Desired Output but is deprecated
[] true
[1.0, 1.0] false
[1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0] false
---comactMap returns a different output then flatmap which is not desired
[[[], [], []]] false
[[[1.0, 1.0], [], []]] false
[[[1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 2.0], [3.0, 3.0]]] false
```

Comment: What output do you want in the end, it's unclear.

Comment: @Larme added some examples clearer examples. TQ

Comment: You can use: `let compacted = array.compactMap { $0.isEmpty ? nil : $0 }` and compare `array.count` vs `compacted.count` to know if it's entirely empty, partially empty (or partially populated, as you wish), or fully populated.

Comment: @Larme didn't work. The nested array is 3 layers down. I've posted how the struct data looks like.

Comment: Point your cursor on "a" holding Alt (to show the question mark), and click on it. It's implicit type should appear. It's different. Now, break `aaa.compactMap{$0.hrInt}.compactMap{$0}.compactMap{$0}` into multiple instructions: `let aaa1= aaa.compact{ $0.hrInt }; let aaa2 = aaa1.compact{$0}; let aaa3 = aaa2.compact{$0}`, `a` being then equals to `aaa`. Do the same with the one with `flatMap()` and compare the types. You'll might see why there is a difference...

Comment: You mean ```[[[Double]]]``` becomes ```[[Double]]``` and finally becomes ```[Double]``` with flatMap? and it remains the same ```[[[Double]]]`` when using ```compactMap()```? How would I get the same result as ```flatMap()``` then?

Comment: Now, let's test `let xxx1 = aaa.flatMap { $0.hrInt }; let xxx2 = xxx1.flatMap { $0 }; let xxx3 = xxx2.flatMap { $0 }`, the compiler complains only with the first one. So if we do `let xxx4 = aaa.compactMap { $0.hrInt }; let xxx5 = xxx4.flatMap { $0 }; let xxx6 = xxx5.flatMap { $0 }`, the output is correct. The issue is because `hrInt` is optional. In that particular case, the `flatMap` need to be `compactMap`, but not for the other ones, as the method then is "different"...

Comment: So use `compactMap()` on the first one, then `flatMap()`...

Comment: Ah.. Yes.. Now I see it. I was wondering also why after broken up like you suggested, Xcode only complaining on the first ```flatMap()``` and not the other 2 subsequent one. TQ So much for the explanation and patience.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're looking for this.

```swift
extension IntervalsData {
  var hrIntIsAtLeastPartiallyPopulated: Bool {
    hrInt?.contains { !$0.isEmpty } ?? false
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this would work if the array was a standalone nested array, but this is an nested array within a struct. Hence, it's ~3 layers deep. I will post the Struc data

Comment: Your edit didn't change the type. Confused.

Comment: The edit, I think, is implicitly saying that the author has an array of `IntervalsData`, but then, I don't understand what's the author's expecting...

Comment: @Larme sorry about that. Trying really hard to get the "correct" example/question worded. I added a playground sample of the data. Hopefully this works better

Answer (score 0):

```
let a = [[],[],[]]  // - case1 (entirely empty)
let b = [[0,0],[],[]] // - case2 (Partially populated)
let c = [[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]] // - case2 (entirely populated)
```

Something is entirely empty if all the things are empty, although you also need to say what to do about an empty list - is that entirely empty too?

```
let aIsEntirelyEmpty = a.allSatisfy(\.isEmpty)  // true
```

Something is partly populated if there is at least one thing where it is empty, and one where it is not

```
let bIsPartlyPopulated = b.contains(where: { !$0.isEmpty }) && b.contains(where: \.isEmpty) // true

let cIsFullyPopulated = c.allSatisfy { !$0.isEmpty } // true
```

You need to say what to do about empty lists - should they be considered all empty (nothing is there) or all populated (because nothing is missing)?

Comment: The array is a nested array within a Struct. Hence I wanted to flatMap it to all into 1 single layer. This way its easy to see if it's entirely empty or not. this is why I needed to do the flatMap 3x. For entirely empty list (of the form in case1, then yes, I want it such that ```.isEmpty = true```)

Comment: ```print(intervalsWodArray.compactMap{$0.hrInt}) = [[[], [], [], [], [], []]]``` this is case1